# simple username password python program

Tags: python

I am a begginer at python and trying to construct a script for an if-structure, which has another if-structure inside it.

I have constructed a script, one of the checks are ok however on a second check i get an error message **"Your program returned a none-zero value. You should return 0 from the main() function"**
(Image attached). would appreciate some help on this thanks! :D

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdEQO.jpg)

My script is the following:

```
username= "john"
password= "ABC123"

name=input("Give Name:")

if name == username: 
   name=input("Give password:")
   if name == password:
      print("Both inputs are correct!")
   else:
      print("The password is incorrect.")
else:
   print("The given name is wrong.")
```

Comment: `'John'` is not the same as `'john'`

Comment: A rookie mistake, thanks dude :)